# Как создать базу в php для 4-язычного сайта?

Tags: php

Я хочу создать 4-язычный сайт, но не знаю, как начать. Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Comment: content => яз1. яз2. яз3. яз4.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как.
Создаете 3 файла словарей (или в БД, что в некотором случае даже лучше).

Типа, например:

```
{
'hello':'здравствуй',
'world':'мир'
}
```

Для всех остальных языков, кроме основного (в качестве него лучше английский).

Все фразы, надписи и тексты выводите через функцию перевода, которая берет из системных настроек текущий язык и переводит фразу.

Comment: > Все фразы, надписи и тексты выводите через функцию перевода, которая берет > из системных настроек текущий язык и переводит фразу.

Ужасный способ, даже слишком.

Comment: Вполне распространенный. Главное, если правильно написать функцию, тормозов наблюдаться не будет.
Скажем, мне этот способ нравится много больше, чем плодить шаблоны.

Answer (score 0):

Сайт статичный? Кто занимается наполнением и как часто? Что именно необходимо переводить? Надо ли переводить текст на изображениях? Будут ли добавляться дополнительные языки в процессе использования? Куча вопросов. Иногда бывает удобнее создать полную копию сайта и сделать адаптацию для другого языка. Расскажите подробнее про задачу.

Comment: Нет, перевода не будет. Просто хочу в базу данных создать поля для 4-язычного сайта, но не знаю, с чего начать.

Comment: Создай таблицу с языками Lang (id, name)

Создай таблицу с текстами Texts (id, text, lang_id)

Дальше определяешь язык, который нужен пользователю, и берешь из базы соответствующие тексты.